# String length changes suddenly

Tags: c++11

Here in this code, the character length is changing suddenly. Before introducing char *file the strlen(str) was correct. As I introduced the new char* file the strlen value of variable str changes.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char buf[BUFSIZ];

    if(!getcwd(buf,BUFSIZ)){
            perror("ERROR!");
    }

    cout << buf << endl;

    char *str;
    str = new char[strlen(buf)];
    strcpy(str,buf);
    strcat(str,"/");
    strcat(str,"input/abcdefghijklmnop");
    cout << str << endl;
    cout << strlen(str) << endl;

    char *file;
    file = new char[strlen(str)];
    cout << strlen(file) << endl;
    strcpy(file,str);
    cout << file << endl;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Your buffer `str` is too short. Why don't you use `std::string`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of [*buffer overflow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). You should be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

You should consider using [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

```
  std::string sbuf;
  {
      char cwdbuf[BUFSIZ];
      if (getcwd(cwdbuf, sizeof(cwdbuf))
        sbuf = cwdbuf;
      else { 
        perror("getcwd");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
 }
 sbuf += "/input/abcdefghijklmnop";
```

You should compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger `gdb`**. Don't forget that strings are zero-byte terminated. Your `str` is much too short. If you insist on avoiding `std::string` (which IMHO you should not), you need to allocate more space (and remember the extra zero byte).

```
str = new char[strlen(buf)+sizeof("/input/abcdefghijklmnop")];
strcpy(str, buf);
strcat(str, "/input/abcdefghijklmnop");
```

Remember that the `sizeof` some literal string is one byte more than its length (as measured by `strlen`). For instance `sizeof("abc")` is 4.

Likewise your `file` variable is one byte too short (missing space for the terminating zero byte).

```
file = new char[strlen(str)+1];
```

BTW on GNU systems (such as Linux) you could use [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) or [`strdup(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) (and use `free` not `delete` to release the memory) and consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).